# i5 vs. i7 MBP Refurb

Tags: macbook-pro, processor

Realistically, besides processing speed, what is the difference between the i5 and i7? Can you really tell a difference? I may be developing apps with it (I haven't tried yet, nor have I ever owned a Mac), so I'd also like to hear from a developer if there is a major difference or preference between the two.

Comment: In fact it's even more complicated than that because some i7 are quad core (15'') others are dual core (13''). So, what model are you thinking about?

Comment: When talking about the 13'' model processors, here's an [official comparison chart of all features](http://ark.intel.com/compare/53464,53450). Differences are highlighted.

Comment: @Matt : make that an answer so we can give you the proper upvotes.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

#### i7 processors differ

I assume - since you are comparing the i5 to the i7 - that you are thinking of the 13'' MBP models. The 15''-17'' MBP models offer only i7 processors.

The i7 processors of the 15''17'' MBP are quad core, while both the i7 and i5 in the 13'' MBP are dual core.

#### 2 important things to notice

- Due to hyper-threading one can also talk of 2 physical cores (4 logical cores) and 4 physical cores (8 logical cores).
- The clock speed you usually see is just the base frequency. The introduced [Intel Turbo Boost](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Intel_Turbo_Boost) technology allows the cores to dynamically clock at higher speeds. However, not all cores at once.

#### Comparison chart

[An offical Intel documentation including all features of all 4 processors can be found here](http://ark.intel.com/compare/53474,53470,53464,53450). The two processors offered in the 13'' MBP are on the right. Differences are highlighted yellow.

Comment: Great stuff guys!!!Huge help thanks a bunch! LOVE THE STACK!!